# How to evaluate RtlDecodePointer from a dump in WinDBG?

Tags: windows, debugging, windbg, dump

I have a crash dump of a user-mode Windows program and I want to emulate `RtlDecodePointer()`, that is, decode some pointer encoded with `RtlEncodePointer()`. How do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I studied disasm of `ntdll!RtlDecodePointer` and was able to compose the following WinDBG expression:

```
r $t0 = 86aaaa40`0007ff77 // put value to decode here
r $t1 = dwo(ntdll!`RtlpGetCookieValue'::`2'::CookieValue)
r $t2 = @$t1 & 3f
r $t3 = (@$t0 >> (0x40 - @$t2)) | (@$t0 << @$t2)
.printf "Decoded pointer: %p\n", @$t3 ^ @$t1
```

Or, as a one-liner:

```
r $t0 = 86aaaa40`0007ff77 // put value to decode here
r $t1 = dwo(ntdll!`RtlpGetCookieValue'::`2'::CookieValue); r $t2 = @$t1 & 3f; r $t3 = (@$t0 >> (0x40 - @$t2)) | (@$t0 << @$t2); .printf "Decoded pointer: %p\n", @$t3 ^ @$t1
```

This works well even on mini-dumps without full memory.